# How to avoid modprobe error could not insert floppy with dracut-pre-udev?

Tags: linux-kernel, kickstart, modprobe

I do have machines or VMs that do not have a floppy drive and I want to avoid getting the below error message while loading the the anaconda kickstart installer on CentOS/Fedora.

Currently the first message appearing after kernel is loaded is

```
dracut-pre-udev[333]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'floppy': No such device
```

I even added the `modprobe.blacklist=floppy` to the kernel options  (append) without any success.

Is there something I can do to avoid this failure? ... other than adding a floppy to the machine. The error is not fatal but I suspect it adds an extra delay at boot time which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: I cut the floppy from my vmware VM master template on the hypervisor/vcenter side. Usually the error only appeared when it was there. Nevertheless, the modprobe blacklisting is not enough, you need to regenerate the initrd

Comment: Does your kernel options really applied? Can you show content of /proc/cmdline?